# Remote Access to MySQL on Raspberry Pi not working

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I installed MySQL on my Raspberry Pi and I'm trying to set up remote access. I set up a user account like so:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON <database>.* TO '<username>'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';`

The connection using MySQL Workbench works when I use the IPv4, but when I use my public IP, it returns error code 10061. I have already commented out the `bind-address` and `skip-external-locking` lines, as well as port-forwarding 3306 TCP, but I don't think that would make a difference as I am on the same network as the Pi. `netstat` also says that MySQL is listening on `0.0.0.0`. What else do I need to do to enable remote access?

Comment: If you are on the same network as the RasPi, then accessing it via the external IP is expected to fail: The overwhelming majority of home routers will not set up the rather complicated rules to allow an "inside-outside-inside" access route. Try accessing it from the real outside.

Comment: I tried using the online MySQL Workbench and it came up with error 111 which implies it isn't allowing remote connections.

Comment: Nevermind, the port forward was incorrect. And using the external IP works for me now on the same network :^)